# tilde and scalable fonts

Tags: pdftex, copy-paste

I regularly use a combination of `pslatex.sty` and `pdflatex` to produce PDF documents. Some of this are for student use and I have come across a problem with the tilde character. Using default LaTeX fonts and `\textasciitilde`, I can copy and paste from the PDF to a Unix terminal window and all is well, but I have yet to find a way of doing this in the presence of `pslatex`

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried $\~$ ?

Comment: You have to use a font encoding that has a tilde in the ASCII position. Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) It's not necessary to sign your questions (as [there is already a box with your username below it](http://tex.stackexchange.com/faq#signatures)) or to begin them with a greeting. A suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user41092".

Comment: Dan's suggestion of fixing the font encoding did the trick, thanks. I should really have thought have that.

Comment: @TeXnician: Wouldn't it be better to add an answer?

Comment: @Dan Do you want to convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: `pslatex.sty` has been obsolete for two decades, more or less.

Comment: @egreg but Graham was there when it was written:-)

Answer (score 1):

To just answer it with Dan's words:

> You have to use a font encoding that has a tilde in the ASCII position. Try `\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}`.

As egreg stated you should also consider alternatives to `pslatex`.

Comment: What constitutes an alternative please?

Comment: @GrahamGough Maybe you want to read the entry on CTAN. There are some references.